# How can client credential authorisation work for multiple clients in an IAM system?

Tags: oauth, jwt

I have an IAM system where each entity entry for client credential flow will be associated with a tenant.

I have two scenarios:

1. one client app that can access target entity to access only client specific data
2. another one that can access the target entity for access data across all clients/tenants.

What's the best way to manage entities (for cc flow) to accommodate the two use cases?